# Bootstrap 3 + Sticky-kit

Tags: sticky

i've been using Bootstrap 3 for a new project and it's being great so far.

The only issue i'm getting is that i need to make a few panels stick to the top of the browser when scrolling down.

I'm trying to use the [Sticky-kit](http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/) but it's not working for me.

HTML

```
<div class="row" data-sticky_parent>
   <div class="col-sm-5" data-sticky_column>content 1...<div>
   <div class="col-sm-7">content 2...<div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(".col-sm-5").stick_in_parent();
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.sticky-kit.min.js"></script>
```

Does anybody know why is the script not working?

Cheers,

Thales Ribeiro

Answer (score 0):

in Bootstrap 3 you can use the build in Affix plugin (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix) to stick any content you want.

Here an example http://bootply.com/103035.

You have to tell js which div (ex.:#alert) you want to stick, and the footer div (ex.:#footer).

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
     $('#alert').affix({
       offset: {
        top: 100
        , bottom: function () {
        return (this.bottom = $('#footer').outerHeight(true))
       }
      }
     })  
    });
```

And create a custom css to .affix, which is the state when the div is sticked.

Comment: Does not really answers the question. Sticky-Kit has a lot more functionality.